# New table in table

Tags: html, css, xslt

this is my  scheme. I would like to add new table in template. What is the best way to display new added table like parent table row ? 
New table will be added foreach rows.

```html
<table>
        <tr>
          <td>
           <xsl:text>text</xsl:text>
          </td>
        </tr>

         <xsl:for-each select=".....">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
         </xsl:for-each>                
    </table>

     <xsl:template match=".....">
        <tr >
          <td >
              <xsl:value-of select="./cbc:ID"/>
          </td>
       </tr>

       <xsl:if test="./jhjj">
       <tr>
            <td colspan="20">
              <table >
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <xsl:text>Text</xsl:text>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <xsl:for-each select="./...">
                  <tr >
                    <td >
                     <xsl:value-of select="./uhuh" />.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr> 
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table in table:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1" bgcolor="yellow" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>2nd table cell</td>
                    <td>2nd table cell</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2nd table cell</td>
                    <td>2nd table cell</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>1st table cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok but what I have to do to not display  the outer edges of the new added table?

Comment: Remove `border="1"` from second table

Comment: Now I haven't  borders inside the table.  I dont now how to merge outer and inner borders of tables

Comment: add  style="border-collapse: collapse;" - I eddited also my answer

Comment: If you like my answer and it is what you were searching for, you can approve my answer